# Should I be concerned if Equifax asks you about a "possible mortgage"?

Tags: mortgage, credit-report

I have been unable to get my online credit reports, and I am planning on sending a written request to see what could be done.

However, something is worrying me: Equifax's FACT check before it tells me that it can't find my credit report asks me about a "possible mortgage" and the monthly payment. I am a junior in college and certainly do not have a mortgage. Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are at the point where the credit agency is attempting to verify your identity, they may very well put up lines of credit that you never had.  Just answer accurately to the two or three questions.

If they can't find you, you might have a problem of just not having much of a report, or worse you might be "married" to another similar account.  For example if you are a Jr. and  your father a Sr. the agencies might have you all mixed up.

Comment: It can be worse than that. My wife shares initials with her mom, their credit reports get entangled all of the time.

Comment: You accurately answer the bogus ones by denying that you have them.

Comment: In fact, they NEED to put up completely bogus lines of credit including mortgages, because otherwise they are leaking information about you to  someone who hasn't proved they are you yet.

Comment: I see, but even after answering the bogus ones as "none of the above," it fails to generate my credit report. I'll try the mail-in option and see what happens... Thanks!

Comment: @A.P. do the mail in, but sounds like another question to ask about how should you fix a "married" credit report.

Comment: I'm not married... or am I being stupid by thinking a "married" here mentions the same thing?

Comment: @A.P. - Having a "married" credit report means two people have each others items reported.  It doesn't have anything to do with a spouse =)